Почему здесь запятая до и после союза И?

Пошел дождь, и, не обращая внимания на этот драгоценный дар неба,
по улицам сновали люди.

Почему здесь запятая перед союзом И, а также после?

Пошёл дождь - одна основа, сновали люди - другая, это сложносочинённые предложение; не обращая на - деепричастный оборот относящийся ко второй части.

В одном предложение два высказывания, не связанные между собой, но относящиеся к общему произошедшему - это ССП и эти части отделяются запятой. Деепричастный оборот так же отдельно обособляется, то есть его границы выделяются запятыми.

@Ильнур Габдуллин А почему вы не принимаете ответ? Качество не устраивает или не все понятно?

День добрый, Sharon. Из ответа нового участника: "из за причастного оборота перед и после союза (И) ставится запятая". Это утверждение никоим образом не является правильным. Да и причастного оборота, собственно, здесь нет. Так что совсем не стоит автору принимать этот ответ.

Да ладно, все и так поняли, Просто хочется поддержать новых участников, которые отвечают  на вопросы. А то одни и те же лица утомили.  Никто к нам не идет, всех "авторитетами" задавили.  Или комментариями о "неправильных" вопросах. Надо объявить месячник новых участников. Скидки и льготы за первый ответ))

"Дык" я вроде правильно себя повела: полезность, конечно, не отметила, но и минусовать не стала. А новых участников я частенько поддерживаю. (Чё, плюсика жалко? Нет, не жалко!) Правда, заглядываю теперь нечасто.

Ну, можно было ответ отредактировать...  термины иногда случайно путают, не стоит за это минусовать.

• Это сложносочиненное предложение, в котором две основы: пошел дождь и сновали люди.
Перед союзом "и" в этом случае ставится запятая.
• За союзом "и" следует деепричастный оборот ("не обращая внимания на этот драгоценный дар неба"), который по правилам необходимо обособить.
Ставим еще одну запятую, теперь уже после союза.
В конце предложения нужна точка.
Пошел дождь, и, не обращая внимания на этот драгоценный дар неба, по улицам сновали люди.
• Вот пример с подобной структурой:
Пошел дождь, и, сойдя с поезда, я увидела маленькую станцию и стоявшую в грязи лошаденку с телегой, на которой приехали меня встречать (Татьяна Окуневская. Татьянин день).
Запятая в сложносочиненном предложении
Деепричастные конструкции

Союз И стоит после первой части сложного предложения, и перед ним ставится запятая. А деепричастный оборот «Не обращая внимания на этот драгоценный дар неба» должен обособляться запятыми с двух сторон.
Так и получается, что из-за деепричастного оборота  после союза И тоже ставится запятая.

Ну! Классно! Только теперь это уже ВАШ ответ, а не участника Jijilo (евойного-то ничего не осталось). Ещё: "из за".

Как не осталось?!  Почти то же самое. чуть-чуть подправила). Проголосуйте, пжста))
